# Symfony 2 - sylius - doctrine is not available

Tags: symfony, doctrine, composer-php, sylius

I have big problem after composer update,

Acctualy I am working with sylius e-commerce on symfony2 (2.8.3).

And few moments ago I did composer update and my symfony version updated to 2.8.4-dev from 2.8.3 and my sylius e-commerce project is not working anymore, acctualy I am getting this error message:

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Doctrine is not available.") in SyliusWebBundle:Frontend:layout.html.twig at line 97.

SYLIUS VERSION IS v0.17.0

Please help me..

Thanks

Comment: Im having the same issue,  my composer has symfony set at 2.8.3  but updated itself to 2.8.4-dev today.  also using sylius.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [known bug](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/4716) in the Sylius 0.17 release (one that I'll personally be looking to fix in the next few days).

In the meantime, you can fix it by manually enabling Doctrine PHPCR:

`app/config/config.yml`:

```
cmf_core:
    persistence:
        phpcr:
            enabled: true
```

Another temporary fix is to open `src/Sylius/Bundle/WebBundle/Resources/Frontend/layout.html.twig` and remove `{% block slideshow_sidebar %}{% endblock %}` and the next ~16 lines up to but not including `{% endblock %}`.

```
         {# delete these lines only #}
            {% block slideshow_sidebar %}{% endblock %}

            {% set links = cmf_children(cmf_find('/cms/pages')) %}
            {% if links is not empty %}
            <h2>{{ 'sylius.ui.links'|trans }}</h2>
            <ul>
              {% for link in links %}
                {% if cmf_is_linkable(link) %}
                    <li>
                      <a href="{{ path(link) }}">{{ link.title|striptags }}</a>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            {% endif %}
```

Comment: I'd rather not install symfony-cmf as I am not using it myself,  is it really necessary for Sylius?..  seems Sylius is tied to too many dependencies.

Comment: it will get installed anyway (via Composer) but you can avoid using it by editing the homepage template, or overriding it - see the updated answer.

Comment: @AdamElsodaney mate, thanks a lot for your advices and solutions, temporary solution worked for me, but I want to ask you, in a case I want to you solution number 1 (Edit app/config/config.yml file), where should I put that block of code?  "cmf_core:
    persistence:
        phpcr:
            enabled: true"

Comment: @billy_56 no worries. yeah you can put it anywhere you like, at the bottom of the file is the more obvious choice, unless there is already a config for `cmf_core` but I doubt it

Comment: @AdamElsodaney thanks a lot mate, have a nice day! :)